# Internet issue on home network

Tags: networking, firewall, home-networking, fortigate

I have a home network and the internet seems to be dropping every few weeks. I have a Fortigate 30E firewall and 2 access point one Meraki and one Ubiquiti. The firewall is connected WAN port by my Virgin Media router LAN, which I turned into modem mode. I have tried the following, but had no luck

I tried checked the system logs, after it got rebooted
I tried checked the external DNS
checked all the policy, but had no luck
check speed and duplex so it matches with the virgin router

Any advice will be greatly appreciated

Many thanks

Nicholas

Comment: Do you have the system logs? It is hard to tell what the problem is as there are a few things that could go wrong and it might be easier with those.

Comment: hi @rtyocum when I looked at the system logs, after it got reboot before it say Fortigate started, it said event memory log is 95% full. I had a look at it and it means it will overwrite the event when reached a certain threshold.

Comment: What type of connection is it to the ISP? Cable, DSL, fiber, Ethernet?